# abstract data of a certain month from CSV file

Tags: scala, csv

I have a CSV file like this:

```
Date,price
2010-01-02,3.658
2010-01-05,3.618
2010-01-06,3.668
2010-01-07,3.628
2010-01-08,3.778
```

All the data in the file have this format `year-01-someday,someprice`

and I want to have a function that should take year as argument. It should read the January data from the given year. The data should be collected in a list of strings for each line in the CSV-file.

currently I have something like this:

```
def get_january_data(year: Int) : List[String] =
{
    val body = scala.io.Source.fromFile("x.csv").mkString
    body.split("\n").toList
}
```

I don't know what to do next ?

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use a Regex pattern to identify and extract the interesting parts of each line of data.

```
def get_january_data(year: Int) : List[String] = {
  val Pattern = s"$year-(\\d+)-(\\d+),(.*)".r
  for {
    Pattern("01", day, price) <- io.Source.fromFile("x.csv").getLines
  } yield price
}.toList

get_january_data(2010)  //res0: List(3.658, 3.618, 3.668, 3.628, 3.778)
```

In this case it ignores the "day" part of the data, but you can make it part of the returned `String`s if it's needed.